# Can you embed python scripts into the web browser?

Tags: python, html, plugins, browser

I'm trying to see how I can get a python script to run in the web browser. Does anyone know if this is possible or would I need to make a plugin?

I'm looking for something that would work like:

```
<embed type="application/x-python" src="myscript.py"></embed>
```

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235629/execute-python-code-inside-browser-without-jython

Comment: that doesn't really answer my question. thanks for finding it though :)

Comment: Would you like to use it on an intranet or extranet application? That is, is it acceptable to require users to install the python environment locally?

Comment: nope. i'm trying to build a lightweight chat application that'll work just by loading up a html page :)

Comment: The closest alternatives to date are listed at http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebBrowserProgramming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you very much to everyone who contributed *hugs to all*

I've decided that i'll just make a netscape-based plugin for python (source code and all that stuff will be availble when i've done it for everyone)

Joe

Comment: Upvoting https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=354630 should get https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/PyDOM to work.

Comment: @ChawatheVipul is there a new ticket for that bug at mozilla?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think any mainstream browser supports this by default so you'd need to write a plugin.

There are people that have tried this before though. For example, [Iron Python + Silverlight](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/silverlight/pycon.html).

Comment: I think using silverlight and python will be a little too much. I'm trying to make this lightweight. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @JoeSimpson I second your opinion. JavaScript as ECMA is uniform, and good remix of predecessor languages, but somehow the blend just builds up "something's wrong" gut feeling that I keep failing to nail. And it keeps getting worse with every interaction with those predecessors. There's skulpt and brython but they use javascript as managed VM layer comparable to faster Silverlight one! Hows your plug-in extension faring?

Answer (score 3):

There is also [brython](http://www.brython.info/) and [PythonScript](http://apppyjs.appspot.com/) but this one is compiled. I forked PythonScript to create Pythonium. There is also pypyjs.

Answer (score 2):

[pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/) might be of interest.