# web: client-side python?

Tags: python, client-side

Is there any way to get Python to run on a web browser, other than silverlight?

I'm pretty sure not, but it never hurts to ask (usually).

Comment: Silverlight runs on Python??? I might have overslept something interesting.

Comment: not sure what exactly you want to do, but this may be useful http://developers.slashdot.org/story/09/09/19/1345236/Python-Converted-To-JavaScript-Executed-In-Browser

Comment: There is a python implementation that runs inside silverlight (ironpython). See http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/silverlight/index.shtml

Comment: @Nikita: No, but Python runs on Silverlight.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute python code inside browser without Jython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235629/execute-python-code-inside-browser-without-jython)

Comment: @Lennart I think the question was edited, there was 'server' instead of 'web browser' initially.

Comment: Possible, but now it's a duplicate. :)

Comment: @Nikita: I was hoping people wouldn't give this as an answer: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/silverlight/index.shtml.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried it myself but Pyjamas (http://pyjs.org/) claims to contain a Python-to-Javascript compiler. Not exactly what you're asking for but might be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly what you asked, but close enough: [Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/) -- Python-to-JavaScript compiler

Answer (score 1):

skulpt is an interesting new project

Answer (score 0):

Short of writing your own browser plugin — no.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open-source project called [emscripten](http://code.google.com/p/emscripten/) that converts C/C++ to JavaScript. The have a version of CPython converted with this tool that runs in the browser as one of their demos.

Probably not something you actually want to do, for a number of reasons, but... it's technically possible. Any Turing-complete language can be converted to any other, after all, and if the languages are popular enough, someone, somewhere, has probably written code to do it.